# Is python 3.8.7 not anymore backward compatible with python 3.4?

Tags: python-3.x

When I run those lines in Python 3.4 everything is fine but when I run with Python 3.8.7 I get these errors:

```
from idlelib.ColorDelegator import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'idlelib.ColorDelegator'
```

or in Tkinter

```
self.s.configure("My.Vertical.TScrollbar", *self.s.configure("Vertical.TScrollbar"))

TypeError: configure() argument after * must be an iterable, not NoneType
```

I had also issues installing 3.9.1 that is the reason why I was forced to install 3.8.7. Even though I checked *"Add Python to path"* it failed to add it. I mean I'm not surprised look only at this window:

[image]

I have no idea what is bellow Includes IDLE, pip and documentation because you can't scroll it.

Comment: Do you possibly have your Windows fonts set to higher than 100%?

Comment: If the question had explicitly asked about whether `idlelib` specifically was subject to backwards-compatibility guarantees, that would have come across a lot less like a rant posed as a question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A simple answer would be

**NOT everything** is backward compatible from python 3.4 -> python 3.8.7
Things like tkinter and other libs that are not a part of standard library or python itself are not being counted as backward compatible

So in fact Python is backward compatible from python 3.4 -> python 3.8.7

Comment: `idlelib` is not part of Python-the-language or the Python standard library; guarantees about the Python language's compatibility don't apply to it. You'll see that `https://docs.python.org/3/library/` does have IDLE documentation, but it only describes that IDLE exists; it doesn't describe its library interface at all, or make any guarantees about what functions that library interface contains.

Comment: In general, backwards compatibility guarantees only apply to documented interfaces. Things that aren't documented interfaces are subject to change without notice. That's not just true in Python -- it's true just about everywhere.

Comment: @Charles Duffy Thank you bringing light to the darkness, now I understand

Answer (score 0):

A simple Google search found: https://github.com/jmmcd/ponyge/issues/7

The following works in Python 3.6 and later.  I don't have 3.4 installed...

```
from idlelib.colorizer import ColorDelegator
```

Comment: I searched for hours but didn't find I'm rly not that guy which asks question immediatelly on SO. thank you